# Nested virtualization with KVM is not working in Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

[If there is a more suitable place to ask this question, let me know !]

## 1 What am I trying to do ?

I want to use `libvirt` `KVM` with **nested virtualization** like described in [1] and [2]. **But it does not work.** It has worked (~ 4 months ago), but not anymore.

I want 2 levels of virtualization like this:

- L0 – the bare metal host, running KVM on `Ubuntu 16.04`
- L1 – a `Ubuntu 16.04` VM running on L0; also called the "guest hypervisor" — as it itself is capable of running KVM
- L2 – a `Ubuntu 16.04` VM running on L1, also called the "nested guest"

[1] https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-nested-virtualization-in-kvm/

[2] https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Nested_Guests

My goal is to deploy an `OpenStack` environnement on top of VMs rather than on bare metal hosts for conveniance for a lab experiment.
As a result, the OpenStack nodes are L1 VMs. Compute nodes are L1 VMs and the VMs created with `OpenStack` and running on the compute nodes are L2 VMs.

## 2 What is my problem ?

I can **not** run my 2nd levels of virtualization:

- L0 is just fine: running `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS`, installed with the `.iso` image
- L1: I install `libvirt` + `KVM` on L0. I can run VMs like the `Ubuntu16.04` cloud image on L0.
- L2: I install `libvirt` + `KVM` on L1 as well. But I **can not** run VMs on L1: I get `kernel panic` or `general protection fault`.

**But if I do the same with Ubuntu18.04** instead of `Ubuntu16.04`, it works without faults.
I don't change the configuration or `virt-install scripts` (other than using the 18.04 .iso and cloud image).

## 3 Details

### Details about L0 Ubuntu 16.04 bare metal host

L0 is running `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS` installed with the .iso.

**kernel**

`user@L0:~$ uname -a
Linux L0 4.4.0-137-generic #163-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 13:14:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**libvirt version** running on L0

`user@L0:~$ virsh version
Compiled against library: libvirt 4.0.0
Using library: libvirt 4.0.0
Using API: QEMU 4.0.0
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.11.1`

**KVM acceleration**

`user@L0:~$ kvm-ok 
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used`

**nested parameter**

`user@L0:~$ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
Y`

**number of CPU**

`user@L0:~$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
48`

### Details about a L1 Ubuntu 16.04 VM

A VM in L1 (which is running on L0) which is running `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS` installed by a cloud image.

**kernel**

`user@L0:~$ uname -a
Linux L1 4.4.0-137-generic #163-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 13:14:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**libvirt version** running on the L1 VM

`user@L1-VM:~$ sudo virsh version
Compiled against library: libvirt 4.0.0
Using library: libvirt 4.0.0
Using API: QEMU 4.0.0
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.11.1`

**KVM acceleration**

`user@L1-VM:~$ kvm-ok 
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used`

**nested parameter**

`user@L1-VM:~$ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
Y`

**number of CPU**, which are vCPU given by L0 to the L1 VM
I give 20 vCPU.

`user@L1-VM:~$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
20`

### Details about a L2 VM

I want to create a L2 `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS` VM installed by a cloud image VM within my L1 `KVM` VM. But whatever I do, my L2 VM crash before finishing to be instantiated. I get `kernel panic` or `general protection fault`.

**However** a Cirros OS image can run on a L1 VM !

## 4 Thoughts

I think this is a bug in eitheir `Ubuntu16.04` or `libvirt`.
I install `libvir KVM` in both L0 and L1 using a custom repository [3] from OpenStack team, because the version of libvirt in this repo is newer than on the one on 16.04 official repo and it match the version of `libvirt` in Ubuntu18.

[3] https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive

If I do the same with `Ubuntu 18.04` .iso and cloud image, it works.

It works if:

- L0 = Ubuntu18.04 (.iso)
- L1 = Ubuntu18.04 (cloud image)
- L2 = Ubuntu18.04 (cloud image)

It also works if:

- L0 = Ubuntu18.04 (.iso)
- L1 = Ubuntu18.04 (cloud image)
- L2 = Ubuntu16.04 (cloud image)

### Thank you for your time reading !

nico

Comment: FYI, I submited a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/1797332) on qemu Ubuntu.

Comment: I would just use 18.04 anyway. It probably was a bug that was fixed years ago.

Comment: You are right and this is why I also started to check Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: However, I may need Ubuntu 16.04 because 18.04 is too fresh, especially when it comes to the framework I use to deploy an OpenStack Environment. I use OSA - OpenStack Ansible. And OSA does not support the deployment of OpenStack Queens over Ubuntu 18.04 but only on 16.04. Maybe they will add the support for 18.04 (but I don't think so). And the newer version of OpenStack Rocky is also a bit too fresh.